# MySql 5.5.41 crashes on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

The MySQL service periodically stops. The error log is empty. The last info in system log before the last crash was

```
Nov 11 09:24:48 qwerty kernel: [2594467.725652] type=1400 audit(1447233888.936:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=19376 comm="apparmor_parser"
Nov 11 09:24:50 qwerty kernel: [2594469.164305] type=1400 audit(1447233890.376:27): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="unlink" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" pid=19388 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="d" denied_mask="d" fsuid=104 ouid=104
Nov 11 09:24:50 qwerty kernel: [2594469.164330] type=1400 audit(1447233890.376:28): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="mknod" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock" pid=19388 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=104 ouid=104
Nov 11 09:24:50 qwerty kernel: [2594469.164495] type=1400 audit(1447233890.376:29): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysql.pid" pid=19423 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="wc" denied_mask="wc" fsuid=104 ouid=104
Nov 11 09:24:50 qwerty kernel: [2594469.164504] type=1400 audit(1447233890.376:30): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="truncate" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysql.pid" pid=19423 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=104 ouid=104
Nov 11 09:24:50 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19428]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Nov 11 09:24:51 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19431]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Nov 11 09:24:51 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19431]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Nov 11 09:24:51 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19431]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Nov 11 09:24:51 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19431]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.41, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Nov 11 09:24:51 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19443]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Nov 11 09:24:51 qwerty /etc/mysql/debian-start[19449]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
```

Could you help me to figure out what it might be?